# How to upload file without post back in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I am uploading jpg image using the fileupload control. The image is uploaded after the page is posted back.

My problem is I want to upload the image immediately after the user double clicks on the file name or presses the open button on the select file dialogue.

I have searched a lot over the internet but I've  been unable to find the suitable example for my application.

How can I achieve this?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at AsyncFileUpload via Ajax

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
    OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server"
    ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern"
    UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" ThrobberID="myThrobber"
/>
```

Comment: sir i want to do this without using ajax control.

Answer (score 2):

you can do with Ajax and Jquery. [Jquery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

html

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/yourMethodToPost/">
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try to use ajax `AsyncFileUpload`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload a file to the Server you always need to do a Postback. However, there are different ways to do a postback. You can use Ajax to do a postback or partial postback.

Take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)